# Oracle and Rails throwing error undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently using Rails 3.2 with the activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter gem. I am connecting to an already existing table in an already existing database. I have created the controller, model, and view files myself (they were not autogenerated).

When I start up a rails server and navigate to localhost:3000/devices, I get the following error - "undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass".

The full stack trace is here:
http://pastebin.com/YfiM7W7S

My MVC for device are printed below:

Model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="DEVICE"
  self.primary_key="DEVICE_NAME_ID"
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Listing devices</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Device Name ID</th>
      <th>Device Desc</th>
      <th>Agg Flg</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @devices.each do |device| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= device.device_name_id %></td>
        <td><%= device.device_desc %></td>
        <td><%= device.agg_flg %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', device %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_device_path(device) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', device, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Device', new_device_path %><head>
```

Controller:

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_device, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /devices
  # GET /devices.json
  def index
    @devices = Device.all
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_device
      @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Including the line where the error occurs would help. But a general answer is that your object is `nil`, that is you have not set it in the controller.

Comment: Sorry, the error being thrown is on line 7. It says that in the stack trace I linked to. How could @devices be nil though? The database gets connected on start-up.

Comment: Line 7 of what, please show the line.

Comment: activerecord (3.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `to_sql'

Comment: You probably have an empty `device` somewhere. Inspect in rails console and remove them and then try to use an unless statement to not show nil values.

Comment: That is not your error line